# Alias CMD command from WSL2 shell

Tags: windows-10, bash, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bash-alias

I'm running WSL2 on Windows 10, and I want to be able to run a CMD command from it without exiting the Linux shell. Specifically, I want to do:

```
wmic diskdrive get Model,Manufacturer,Size,DeviceID,Status,InterfaceType
```

How can I do this with WSL2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others more knowledgeable than me may know of better methods or be able to suggest improvements, but the easiest way I could think of to solve this was to use a Bash alias. I created an alias called `lsd` (short for **l**i**s**t **d**evices or **d**isks) that I can run without ever needing to leave the WSL shell, while it remains as fast as running the command in CMD itself.

---

From a WSL shell, navigate to your home folder:

```
cd ~
```

...and open it in Windows Explorer:

```
explorer.exe .
```

Open the `.bashrc` file in your home folder with a plain text editor like Sublime Text, and add the following line to the bottom of it:

```
alias lsd="cmd.exe /c '*wmic diskdrive get Model,Manufacturer,Size,DeviceID,Status,InterfaceType'"
```

This creates an alias (another command, for all intents and purposes) called `lsd` that runs an instance of CMD, which executes the `wmic` command before terminating itself. Remember to replace my `wmic` command above with the CMD command that you want to run.

Save the `.bashrc` file, then load it into the shell by doing:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

You can then simply run the alias like any other WSL command:

```
$ lsd

'\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\user'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
DeviceID            InterfaceType  Manufacturer            Model                                 Size           Status
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  IDE            (Standard disk drives)  WDC WD10PURX-64E5EY0                  1000202273280  OK
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE4  IDE            (Standard disk drives)  WDC WD30EZRZ-00GXCB0                  3000590369280  OK
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  IDE            (Standard disk drives)  CT250MX500SSD1                        250056737280   OK
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE6  USB            (Standard disk drives)  Seagate GoFlex Desk USB Device        3000582144000  OK
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  IDE            (Standard disk drives)  KINGSTON SV200S3128G                  128034708480   OK
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3  IDE            (Standard disk drives)  ST2000DM001-9YN164                    2000396321280  OK
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE5  USB            (Standard disk drives)  Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 USB Device  15471751680    OK
```

As seen above, my implementation of the alias does come with the non-fatal bug that the command returns a path error just before executing, but I haven't had the time to figure out how to solve this ([follow-up question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1541303/convert-unc-path-to-wsl-path)). In any case, Windows corrects the issue itself, meaning it doesn't prevent the CMD command from executing as normal, and that the only real harm it does is make the output a little uglier than it should be.

Comment: You can avoid the CMD path error message by doing `pushd` to somewhere suitable before the `cmd` part, and `popd` afterward, for example here's how I start a VNC session to wsl - `vncgo` is an executable bash script that starts the VNC server, and `wslxvnc.bat` is a CMD batch script on the Windows path that invokes a `.vnc` file associated with my Windows VNC viewer  `alias stx='/usr/local/bin/vncgo >/dev/null; sleep 0.5; pushd /mnt/c >/dev/null; /mnt/c/Windows/SysWOW64/cmd.exe /c wslxvnc; popd >/dev/null'`