# Convert UNC path to WSL path

Tags: windows-10, bash, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux, unc

I created an alias as part of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1541301/alias-cmd-command-from-wsl2-shell). It functions as expected except that whenever it's run from the home directory it outputs a non-fatal error:

```
'\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\hashim'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

According to [a prominent WSL contributor](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4079#issuecomment-497482601), this is fixed by simply  changing from the UNC path that the WSL home directory is located at to anything under `/mnt/`:

```
alias lsd="builtin cd $(wslpath $(cmd.exe /c "echo %USERPROFILE%") | tr -d '\r') && cmd.exe /c 'wmic diskdrive get Model,Manufacturer,Size,DeviceID,Status,InterfaceType'"
```

The above works to convert the Windows user profile path to a WSL path and CD into it before running the command, but it comes with the disadvantage that it requires a `cd` to an arbitrary path - the Windows user profile in this case - and can't be brought back to the previous directory.

I've had a quick go at both:

- Converting the current UNC path at ~ to a `/mnt/` path using `wslpath`
- Using `pushd` and `popd` to manually change to an arbitrary `/mnt/` directory and then change back to the original directory

...but I didn't manage to get either of these solutions working.

Is what I want possible?

Comment: I don't have WSL2 but you could try adding " ; cd -" after the cmd.exe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can add `&& builtin cd -` which is the bash equivalent of `cd $OLDPWD`

It has a disadvantage though: you lose the previous value of $OLDPWD. Personally I would find it very annoying and not a good solution for a command that's run often. I think in this case it's acceptable.

Hopefully someone else comes up with a better solution!

Comment: `pushd /mnt/c` before and `popd` after works for me, with `>/dev/null` appended to each if you like. For example `alias windir='pushd /mnt/c; cmd.exe /c dir;  popd'`